# Cannot read property 'emoji' of undefined

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make it so I can verify someones question but the usual reaction.emoji.name check doesn't work. It says that it's undefined. But I've used it so many times without defining it. I'm very lost help would be appreciated.

```js
    const {Client, Collection, GuildMember, User, MessageEmbed, Message} = require("discord.js");
    module.exports.run = async(client, message, args, member, reaction) => {
        var woord = '!poll' 
        var question = args.slice(0).join(' ') 
        var pollChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.id === `875406886986477569`)
        var poll = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`${message.author.username} wil een poll maken.`)
            .setDescription(question)
            .setColor('#eb8dd8')
            .setFooter(`Poll gemaakt door: `+ message.author.username)
    
        var success = new MessageEmbed()
            .setDescription(question)
            .setColor('#eb8dd8')
            .setFooter("Poll started door: "+ message.author.username)
    
            
    
        if(message.content.includes(woord)) {
            message.delete({timeout:0}) 
        }
    
        if(message.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === 'Barman')) {
            if(message.channel.name.includes("-poll")) {
                if(args[1]) {
                    message.delete()
                    message.guild.channels.create(message.author.username, { permissionOverwrites:[
                        {
                            deny: 'VIEW_CHANNEL',
                            id: message.guild.id
                        },
                        {
                            allow: 'VIEW_CHANNEL',
                            id: message.author.id
                        },
                    ],
                }).then(channel => {
                    channel.send(poll).then(poll => {
                        poll.react('✅')
                        .then(() => poll.react('❌'));
                    })
                })
    
                } else {
                    message.delete()
                }
            }
        }
        
        if(reaction.emoji.name === '✅') {
            console.log('check!')
        }
    }
    
    module.exports.help = {
        name: "test"
    }
```

Comment: Try doing `console.log(reaction)`, it might be null or undefined.
Also, to control the error you can use JS optional chaining feature if you are using the latest node version.
`reaction?.emoji?.name`

Comment: tried the `console.log(reaction)` but still gives off TypeError: Cannot read property 'emoji' of undefined

Comment: also tried this


const filter = (reaction, user) => {
        return ['✅', '❌'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === interaction.user.id;
    };
    
    message.awaitReactions({ filter, max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
 .then(collected => {
  const reaction = collected.first();

  if (reaction.emoji.name === '✅') {
   console.log(reaction);
  } else {
   message.reply('You reacted with a thumbs down.');
  }
 }).catch(console.error('error'));

Comment: The purpose of logging the reaction object on the console was to debug. It won't fix your error. What did you see on the console? Is your reaction object empty? Or it has the **emoji** property in it?
Also, please use `reaction?.emoji?.name` instead of `reaction.emoji.name`.

Comment: How do you execute your function? This could be in your main file, or an event handler.